# Check for sub-div mouse-hover

Tags: jquery, html

Im not 100% sure how to ask this question. Please edit it if you understand.

I want to check for a sub-div mouse-over event.
But its not working. My current code is this:

```
$('#mc').hover(function() {
    if (selectedCoding !== 1)
        $(this).css({"color":"red"});
    else
        $(this).css({"color":"white"});
}, function() {
    if (selectedCoding !== 1)
        $(this).css({"color":"white"});
    else
        $(this).css({"color":"red"});
});
```

This is where #mc is:

```
<div id="coding">
    <ul>
        <li id="mc">
            <img src="images/minecraft.png">
            <h3>Minecraft Plugins</h3>
            <p>Description text</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem here is that it doesn't find #mc in the jQuery function.

In my index.php file, i have this little code:

```
$('#webbox').load('codinghelp.html');
```

Everything below is inside "codinghelp.html":

```
    <div id="coding">
    <ul>
        <li id="mc">
            <img src="images/minecraft.png">
            <h3>Minecraft Plugins</h3>
            <p>Description text</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<span style="color:green" id="request"> </span>
```

I can't find #mc from my index.php file, but i can find #request, because this code works:

```
$('#request').text('Minecraft');
```

Comment: Outside my code. Its changes when i select something from a menu.

Comment: Where is _its not working_ defined?

Comment: My bad, i forgot to mention that. I will update the question and add that right now.

Comment: This already looks like it would be easier with a `.toggleClass()` and some CSS applied with the two different colors.

Comment: Is `#mc` dynamically created by some other browser event or method? You may need delegation.. `$(document).on('hover','#mc',function() {` as your first line of code.

Comment: are you using `document.ready`?

Comment: I will update my question with more details

Comment: You've gone this far, just make a jsFiddle

Comment: Now that the original issue is resolved, you should open a new issue for your click handler question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use CSS to handle this, then you won't need to worry about event binding and dynamic elements. You'll just need to set the class on `mc` when the value of `selectedCoding` changes.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yRgvF/1)**

**jQuery**

```
$('#mc').addClass((selectedCoding !== 1 ? 'selected' : 'selectedInverse'));
```

**CSS**

```
.selected {
    color: white;
}
.selected:hover {
    color: red;
}

.selectedInverse {
    color: red;
}
.selectedInverse:hover {
    color: white;
}
```